# C#: menu item not showing when debugging

Tags: c#, menu

So I have added a "Menu" item to my program and though properties:

```
IsEnabled: (is checked)
visibility: Visible
```

And my .xaml shows:

```
 <Grid>
    <Menu Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="504" Opacity="88">
    <MenuItem Header="_Menu"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_View"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Edit"/>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

When I debug the program the "Menu" or any of the MenuItems does not show up on the Active Windows Form.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I just realized I can't see any items added from the toolbox.

Comment: Define Rowdefinitions and Set Grid.Row property of the Menu control.

Comment: If this is the entire content of the window, it should work.  Please post more of your code.

@Anuraj - you do not need to do this.  The entire content of the Grid is the menu in this case, defaulting to column 0, row 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a technical issue that I straightened out that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add right after your window element `<DockPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" LastChildFill="True">`

And then add this attribute into your menu element: `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you explicitly save and re-compile your application after making XAML changes.

I've personally had a lot of instances where XAML changes simply did not show up when debugging an application. To be sure your changes are going through, you can clean the solution and rebuild.